# Compare data in tables between SQL Server and linked server

Tags: java, sql-server, comparison

Currently we are doing database archiving project. As part of this, around 1200 tables in SQL Server database which contains records from as low as 100 to as high as 8million are being archived. From our DBA, I came to know that these tables are being archived to flat files and they have setup linked server and can be accessed via SSMS.

I need to validate the count, schema and the data between the SQL server source tables and destination tables in linked server.

I am looking for any options for comparing the data between the source and destination efficiently.

What I am trying?

1. Writing Java code to query source and destination tables and export the data to CSV and compare the data and generate results.

While doing the above solution, I found that easiest way to do comparison is using SQL queries. I need help in this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server Data Tools you can run  a [Data Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-compare-and-synchronize-the-data-of-two-databases?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=To%20compare%20data%20by%20using%20the%20New%20Data,the%20data%20comparison.%20...%205%20Click%20Finish.%20) between two databases.
[image]

You don't need a Visual Studio license to use the SQL Server Data Tools.  Just install the Visual Studio Community Edition, per the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#install-ssdt-with-visual-studio-2019).  Just don't use the other development workloads if you don't qualify as a "Community Edition" user.

Or you can use the commandline [tablediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/tablediff-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) that comes with SQL Server.